# O aviso sobre encurtamento de URL não foi traduzido

Tags: bug, status-aceito, tradução, internacionalização

Fazendo a [edição de uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/247079/2) hoje, recebi o seguinte aviso:

> O corpo não pode conter "https://goo.gl/EGXzpw".
>
> Please avoid using URL shorteners; they can break without leaving any useful artifact and are often used to obscure spam or malicious links. 
>   Editors: please replace the short URL noted above with the URL it redirects to!
>   For details, see meta.

Entendi que não é possível utilizar as URL encurtadas devido a possibilidade de spam ou links maliciosos.

Particularmente, acho que poderíamos traduzir esse aviso para uma mensagem semelhante a essa:

> O corpo não pode conter a URL encurtada: "https://goo.gl/EGXzpw".
>
> Por favor, evite utilizar encurtadores de URL¹; eles podem quebrar sem deixar nenhuma informação útil² e geralmente costumam ser usados para obscurecer *spam* ou links maliciosos.
>   Editores: substituam o URL curto observado acima com o URL ao qual redireciona!
>   Para mais detalhes, veja o [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64450).

- 1: Em encurtamentos de URL fiquei em dúvida de como traduzir o *Short URL* e *URL Shortener*. Na minha opinião, acho que poderíamos usar URLs encurtadas.
- 2: Não entendi muito bem o "*artefato útil*". Se tiver uma tradução melhor, por favor comentem.

---

## English version

While editing [this question](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/247079/2), I got the following warning:

> O corpo não pode conter "https://goo.gl/EGXzpw".
>
> Please avoid using URL shorteners; they can break without leaving any useful artifact and are often used to obscure spam or malicious links. 
>   Editors: please replace the short URL noted above with the URL it redirects to!
>   For details, see meta.

I got that it isn't possible to use shortened URLs due to spam and malicious uses.

However, I think we should translate this to something like:

> O corpo não pode conter a URL encurtada: "https://goo.gl/EGXzpw".
>
> Por favor, evite utilizar encurtadores de URL¹; eles podem quebrar sem deixar nenhuma informação útil² e geralmente costumam ser usados para obscurecer *spam* ou links maliciosos.
>   Editores: substituam o URL curto observado acima com o URL ao qual redireciona!
>   Para mais detalhes, veja o [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64450).

- 1: I wasn't sure how to translate *Short URL* and *URL Shortener*, so I think we can just use "URLs encurtadas."
- 2: Not really sure about "useful artifact." Plase comment if you have a better translation.

Comment: Desculpa, deve ser falta de atenção da minha parte, mas você fala em  "artefato útil", de onde saiu isso?

Comment: Eu também gostaria de saber o que é esse "artefato útil" @LINQ. Ele seria dessa parte *"without leaving any **useful artifact** and are often"*.

Comment: "Eles podem quebrar sem deixar **algo útil** e são geralmente usadas para ofuscar _spam_ e links maliciosos"?

Comment: Acho que é isso mesmo @JeffersonQuesado